# Structure or syntax for empty if/elsif/else block in perl

Tags: perl

This amounts to testing for xor (one or the other but not both and not neither) where the task demands something is done for the one but not for the other but we abandon the project if both or neither.

This example might be most to the point but the empty block doesn't sit well with me

```perl
if (condition == 1) {
  do something
}
elsif (condition == 2) {
  ; # do nothing aka carry on
}
else {
  exit;
}
```

Nesting seems no better and in this example misses (ie, does not validate) the second condition

```perl
if (condition) {
  if (condition == 1) {
    do something
  }
}
else {
  exit;
}
```

Combining both of the above avoids the empty block and will work but forces redundant testing and seems inefficient.

```perl
if ((condition == 1) || (condition == 2)) {
  if (condition == 1) {
    do something
  }
}
else {
  exit;
}
```

Is there an alternative I haven't thought of? Why might one choose one structure over another? Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (condition == 1) {
  do something
}
elsif (condition == 2) {
  ; # do nothing aka carry on
}
else {
  exit;
}
```

and

```
if ((condition == 1) || (condition == 2)) {
  if (condition == 1) {
    do something
  }
}
else {
  exit;
}
```

are equivalent to

```
if (condition == 1) {
  do something
}
elsif (condition != 2) {
  exit;
}
```

None of the above test for "one or the other but not both and not neither". For that, you'd need the following:

```
if (condition == 1 || condition == 2) {
  do something
}
```

Since `condition` can't be both 1 and 2, no further checks are needed. On the other hand, if you had two independent conditions, you could literally use xor.

```
if (condition1 xor condition2) {
  do something
}
```

Warning: This is a low-precedence operator (like `not`, `and` and `or`), so you may need to put parens around both of the expressions it has for operands.

Comment: I think looking for a positive match blinded me to your equivalent (condition != 2) example. On top of that, I probably misread the final paragraph on [this page](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl3/prog/ch03_20.htm). Not that that would have helped because even the use of xor would involve an additional evaluation - which is what I've been trying to work around. So, thank you for the clarification. Perfect!

Comment: Well, there's `elsif (!(condition == 2))` if you want something more positive.

Answer (score 0):

```
my %dispatch = {
    1 => sub { dosomething() },
    2 => sub { dosomethingelse() },
}

exists $dispatch{$condition}  ?
    $dispatch{$condition}->() :
    do_default();
```